# How to trigger a hover event for map graphics in ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to trigger an event when the user hovers over a geometry that they drew. I know how to set up hover events for DOM objects, but not for graphic elements within the map window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GraphicsLayer has an [onMouseOver](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/graphicslayer.htm#onMouseOver) event ([doc](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/graphicslayer.htm#onMouseOver)).  Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

```
dojo.connect(yourLayer, "onMouseOver", function(evt) {

    map.setMapCursor("pointer");
});

dojo.connect(map.graphics, "onMouseOut", function(evt) {
    map.graphics.clear();
    map.setMapCursor("default");
});
```