# ArcGIS JS API 4.4 - mouse over (hover) event

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to write a handler for a mouse-over event on a FeatureLayer in ArcGIS JS API 4.4. It seems in the previous [API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_hover.html) this was built in, but I'm not finding it anywhere in the new [API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#methods-summary). Am I missing something or was this just lost in the overhaul? If so, is there a workaround?

This [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6816/how-to-trigger-a-hover-event-for-map-graphics-in-arcgis-javascript-api) mentions an option but the link doesn't take you there, I'm guessing this was for the old API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [hitTest](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#hitTest) for this type of interaction. There's a [discussion](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/192980-viewhittest-throwing-error-when-triggered-by-views-pointer-move-event) on GeoNet that shows how to do this, using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta name="description" content="[Access features with click events - 4.3]">
<!--
ArcGIS API for JavaScript, https://js.arcgis.com
For more information about the view-hittest sample, read the original sample description at developers.arcgis.com.
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/view-hittest/index.html
-->
<title>Access features with click events - 4.3</title>

<style>
html,
body,
#viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#info {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.75;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding: 8px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/"></script>

<script>
require([
  "esri/core/watchUtils",
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  watchUtils,
  Map,
  MapView,
  FeatureLayer,
  UniqueValueRenderer,
  SimpleLineSymbol,
  dom
) {

  var layer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hurricanes/MapServer/1",
    outFields: ["*"]
  });

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "dark-gray",
    layers: [layer]
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-61.125537, 35.863534],
    zoom: 4
  });

  view.ui.add("info", "top-right");


  function changeCursor(response){
    if (response.results.length > 0){
      document.getElementById("viewDiv").style.cursor = "pointer";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("viewDiv").style.cursor = "default";
    }
  }

  function getGraphics(response) {
    // the topmost graphic from the click location
    // and display select attribute values from the
    // graphic to the user
    var graphic = response.results[0].graphic;
    var attributes = graphic.attributes;
    var category = attributes.CAT;
    var wind = attributes.WIND_KTS;
    var name = attributes.NAME;

    dom.byId("info").style.visibility = "visible";
    dom.byId("name").innerHTML = name;
    dom.byId("category").innerHTML = "Category " + category;
    dom.byId("wind").innerHTML = wind + " kts";

    // symbolize all line segments with the given
    // storm name with the same symbol
    var renderer = new UniqueValueRenderer({
      field: "NAME",
      defaultSymbol: layer.renderer.symbol || layer.renderer.defaultSymbol,
      uniqueValueInfos: [{
        value: name,
        symbol: new SimpleLineSymbol({
          color: "orange",
          width: 5,
          cap: "round"
        })
      }]
    });
    layer.renderer = renderer;
  }

  view.then(function() {
    view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(lview) {
      watchUtils.whenFalseOnce(lview, "updating", function(){
        // Set up a click event handler and retrieve the screen x, y coordinates 
        view.on("pointer-move", function(evt) {
            var screenPoint = {
              x: evt.x,
              y: evt.y
            };

            // the hitTest() checks to see if any graphics in the view
            // intersect the given screen x, y coordinates
            view.hitTest(screenPoint)
              .then( function(response){
                changeCursor(response);
                getGraphics(response);
              });      
        });
      });
    });
    layer.then(function() {
      // update the default renderer's
      // symbol when the layer loads
      var renderer = layer.renderer.clone();
      renderer.symbol.width = 4;
      renderer.symbol.color = [128, 128, 128, 0.8];
      renderer.symbol.cap = "round";
      layer.renderer = renderer;
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
<div id="info">
<span id="name"></span><br>
<span id="category"></span><br>
<span id="wind"></span>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes it looks like the [View](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-View.html#events-summary) object contains a "pointer-move" event which MapView inherits.